# Play Framework: How to deal with api keys

Tags: scala, playframework, api-key

I've implemented a REST API that handles user authorization with JWT (Json Web Token) and it works fine. Now I'm wondering how to deal with API keys to prevent unauthorized applications from using my API.

The idea would be to add the API key in the request header and implement a custom action builder for it. Now the question is: since I already have a custom action builder that handles  authorization tokens, how do I integrate the new custom action builder?

Assuming this is my JWT custom action builder...

```
class ApiRequest[A](
  val token: Token,
  request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request) {

  ...
}

class SecuredAction extends ActionBuilder[ApiRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (ApiRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
  ...
  }
}
```

... and this one my api_key custom action builder

```
class ApiKeyRequest[A](
  val apiKey: String,
  request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request) {

  ...
}

class ApiKeyAction extends ActionBuilder[ApiKeyRequest] {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (ApiKeyRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
  ...
  }
}
```

... how do I use them together in my controller?

```
object MyController extends Controller {

  // here I need to compose SecuredAction with ApiKeyAction...
  def doSomething = SecuredAction.async { implicit request => 
    ...
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Action Composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition), it allows you to inspect and transform a request on an action. If you use a Play Filter then it will be run on EVERY request made.

For example you can make a TokenAction which inspects the request and if a token has been found then refine the request to include the information based on the token, for example the user. And if no token has been found then return another result, like Unauthorized, Redirect or Forbidden.

I made a SessionRequest which has a user property with the optionally logged in user, it first looks up an existing session from the database and then takes the attached user and passes it to the request

A filter (WithUser) will then intercept the SessionRequest, if no user is available then redirect the user to the login page

```
// Request which optionally has a user
class SessionRequest[A](val user: Option[User], request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

object SessionAction extends ActionBuilder[SessionRequest] with ActionTransformer[Request, SessionRequest] {

  def transform[A](request: Request[A]): Future[SessionRequest[A]] = Future.successful {
    val optionalJsonRequest: Option[Request[AnyContent]] = request match {
      case r: Request[AnyContent] => Some(r)
      case _ => None
    }

    val result = {
      // Check if token is in JSON request
      for {
        jsonRequest <- optionalJsonRequest
        json <- jsonRequest.body.asJson
        sessionToken <- (json \ "auth" \ "session").asOpt[String]
        session <- SessionRepository.findByToken(sessionToken)
      } yield session
    } orElse {
      // Else check if the token is in a cookie
      for {
        cookie <- request.cookies.get("sessionid")
        sessionToken = cookie.value
        session <- SessionRepository.findByToken(sessionToken)
      } yield session
    } orElse {
      // Else check if its added in the header
      for {
        header <- request.headers.get("sessionid")
        session <- SessionRepository.findByToken(header)
      } yield session
    }

    result.map(x => new SessionRequest(x.user, request)).getOrElse(new SessionRequest(None, request))
  }
}

// Redirect the request if there is no user attached to the request
object WithUser extends ActionFilter[SessionRequest] {
  def filter[A](request: SessionRequest[A]): Future[Option[Result]] = Future.successful {
    request.user.map(x => None).getOrElse(Some(Redirect("http://website/loginpage")))
  }
}
```

You can then use it on a action

```
def index = (SessionAction andThen WithUser) { request =>
  val user = request.user
  Ok("Hello " + user.name)
}
```

I hope this will give you an idea on how to use Action Composition